# Fire Session_OnEnd using "Custom" session mode

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, azure-storage, azure-caching, state-management

I am using Azure Caching to store session state for that i have to change the Session mode to "Custom" from "InProc".  It's working fine i am able to create and use sessions as well as session is being expired at the time specified in the web.config. The problem is using session mode (Custom) stops firing Session_OnEnd() in global.asax  on session expiry.

I know the Session_OnEnd() only fires if session mode is set to "InProc". Please suggest me is their any way i can capture the Session_OnEnd using Custom mode or any alternative to run a event on session expiry.

Thanks

Pankaj